# What is the purpose of dimension reduction in classification?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

We use Principal Component Analysis for dimension reduction, why is it important?

Comment: To deal with `Curse of Dimensionality`.

Comment: To reduce dimensionality.

Comment: This is two-fold question, actually two questions. (1) Why would we use dim. red. techniques like PCA, which do not belong to classification domain, _before_ a classification. Is it useful? (2) Why some classification techniques, like LDA (discrim. analysis), are themselves special dim. reduction methods; what's the reason to do dim. red. _on the way_ of classifying?